Rotating an object in x,y and z planes
I Use the following code to draw a dental syringe in different locations in the document in relation to other drawings.
Is it possible to rotate the syringe in the z plane in addition to the x and y planes!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\lnth{3}
\def\wdth{.74}
%
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
  pic dentsyrg/.style={code={
%body
\draw[line width=.4mm
, right color=gray, left color=gray, middle color=gray!50
] (0,0) node (o) {} --++ (90:\lnth) node (ul) {} --++ (0:\wdth) node [midway](md){}node (ur){} --++ (-90:\lnth) to [out=-90,in=-90]  node [midway](mdp){} (o.center) -- cycle;
%nozzle
\draw[line width=.4mm
, right color=gray, left color=gray, middle color=gray!50
] (ul.center) to [out=80,in=-170]  ([shift={(20:.28)}]ul.center) node (ulr){} --++ (90:.28cm) --++ (0:.11cm) --++ (0:.11cm) --++ (-90:.28cm) to [out=-10,in=100] (ur.center);
%needle
\draw[line width=.2mm] ([shift={(180:.04)}]ulr.center) --++ (90:.3cm) --++ (0:.12cm) node (ulrr){} --++ (90:\lnth*.6) --++ (-60:.12cm) to [out=-90,in=90] ([shift={(0:.06)}]ulrr.center) --++ (0:.12cm) --++ (-90:.3cm);
%plunger
\draw[line width=.4mm
, right color=gray, left color=gray, middle color=gray!50
] ([shift={(180:.11)}]mdp.center) --++ (-90:\lnth*.7) node (plngl) {} --++ (0:.22cm) node (plngr) {}  --++ (90:\lnth*.7);
%handle
\draw[line width=.4mm
, right color=gray, left color=gray, middle color=gray!50
] (plngl.center) to [out=-90,in=90] ([shift={(-170:1)}]plngl.center) to [out=-90,in=180] ([shift={(-90:.34)}]plngl.center) to [out=0,in=-90] ([shift={(-10:1)}]plngr.center)to [out=90,in=-90] (plngr.center);
%body bottom
\draw[line width=.4mm
, right color=gray, left color=gray, middle color=gray!50
] ([shift={(90:.04)}]mdp.center) to [out=180,in=90] ([shift={(180:1.)}]mdp.center) to [out=-90,in=180] ([shift={(-90:.04)}]mdp.center) to [out=0,in=-90] ([shift={(0:1.)}]mdp.center)to [out=90,in=0] ([shift={(90:.04)}]mdp.center);
%midline % for alignment
%\draw[line width=.1mm, red] ([shift={(90:2.5)}]md.center) -- ++ (-90:8.5cm);
}}
}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\pic  [rotate=180] at (0,0) {pic dentsyrg};
\pic [rotate=-45] at (5,0) {pic dentsyrg};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



no. and some more.

@cfr What do you mean by "and some more"!

the system doesn't allow comments that short so people add and some more or ......... or 12345 or whatever ;).

@cfr Thank you for your comment

I realise it seems negative and, after all, it is. most people will not bother to say 'no'. in part that's in case the answer is really 'yes'. but sometimes that means nobody ever actually says 'no'. and, in this case, there is really no way the answer could be 'yes'. except you could write completely different code. but you can't rotate what you have the way you ask. there isn't anything like sufficient information, even if tikz knew about 3d, which it doesn't. 3d in tikz is just 2d. the software has no concept of it.

@cfr Thank you for your comment

What do you mean by "the z plane" do you mean the "xz plane" or the "yz plane" or as you say rotate, you probably mean the "z axis"!? The syringe is as far as the information available already rotational symmetric. -So what do you mean?

@hpekristiansen this is a 2 dimensional rotation in the x and y axis. I need to rotate it in the z axis as well, to give the illusion of making an angle to the background.

Sorry I am unable to understand what you mean. A plane and an axis is not the same thing.

What you have is just a 2D graphic. You probably mean to rotate it around the y axis on the xy plane (x and y used as in 2D notation). This essentially means to scale the 2D graphics along the x axis, but not along the y axis, which you can achieve using the option xscale. But I am unsure whether this is the effect you want.
